# Bootstrap Form Null

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried to fix this the past hour, but it won't give a good result.
The problem is that I've got a new bootstrap theme, I'm bussy with building my old system into the new theme. The only thing is that when I push on the submit It won't do anything.
If I try to check the variables with var_dump it gives me null. The only problem is that I don't know why the form is wrong.

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
<!-- Username -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Gebruikersnaam</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Password -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Wachtwoord</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Inloggen">
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
  </div>
  <br />
</form>
<div class="widget-foot"> Nog niet geregistreerd? <a href="#">Registreer hier</a></div>
```

**PHP**

```
/* Start of the script.. */
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 global $sFoutmelding;

  $stringaUser   =  trim($_POST['username']);
  $stringaPass   =  trim($_POST['password']);
  $smallUser     =  strtolower($stringaUser);
  $hashPass      =  hash("SHA512", $stringaPass);

    //Begin of the prepared statement.
       $stmt     = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT gebruikersnaam,wachtwoord FROM users WHERE gebruikersnaam = ?");
       $stmt->bind_param('s', $smallUser);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->store_result();
     $stmt->bind_result($arrayUserName, $arrayUserPass);
     $stmt->fetch();
     $stmt->close();
    //End of the prepared statement.

  if(empty($stringaUser))
  {
    $sFoutmelding[] = 'U hebt geen gebruikersnaam opgegeven!';
  }
  if(empty($stringaPass))
  {
    $sFoutmelding[] = 'U hebt geen wachtwoord opgegeven!';
  }
  if($smallUser != $arrayUserName)
  {
    $sFoutmleding[] = 'Uw gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord klopt niet!'; 
  }
  if($hashPass != $arrayUserPass)
  {
    $sFoutmelding[] = 'Uw gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord klopt niet!';
  }
}
```

Thank you for helping^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `name` attribute to your `submit` button and check against that name on line 1.